# specify cache output folder?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, path, cache

Can I set my cache output folder? I'm using Cycles Rendering, with GPU mode, my computer sometimes show a message that I have little space left.
This happens while I work, sometimes without even rendering as preview.

Comment: Do you mean can you find it to delete it, or do you mean can you configure it?

Comment: To configure it, and maybe to delete it too :)

Comment: what is the specific error message that you are getting?

Comment: Hmm, my main language is spanish so the message says something like the main disk (C folder) is running out of space, it appears as a little white window near the volume settings and hour on the task bar.
Same happens if open a giant image on Photoshop, like a 10K image or something with high resolution. (On this case i'm only using Full HD proportions).

Comment: Exactly, you need to clean your C drive. THis has to be done periodically. Just go through and manually check the properties of each folder (RMB>Properties) and delete any unnecessary ones. Also remove all files from the recycle bin and tmp folders. You should have a 1GB+ or ~10% (whichever is more) range that applications can use, otherwise your system will start to slow down. Never save files onto your C drive if you have a dual drive system.